# Tikz's custom shape fails when groupplots library is loaded

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, groupplots, tikz-shape

I am using a `book` documentclass to write a report where I draw some circuit/block schematics using a custom `tikz` shape called `dff` that I originally found [here](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/d-flip-flops-and-shift-register/) and then slightly customised.

Everything works fine until I add `tikz`'s `groupplots` library (for some other plot not shown in the MWE below) to my preamble. Then, my custom shape can no longer be drawn and all I get is a huge amount of "undefined control sequences" and "Package PGF Math" errors that appear to relate to my `dff` shape but that I cannot make sense of.

The MWE below shows the complete preamble that I used to precisely pinpoint the conflicting command; simply uncomment the line with `\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}` to see it fail. Any help or suggestion on how to tackle this issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
    \def\subfigureautorefname{Fig.}
    \def\figureautorefname{Fig.}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{{./img/}}
    \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf}

\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}
    \creflabelformat{equation}{#2#1#3}
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{exponent-product=\cdot,detect-all}

\usepackage{pgfplots, tikz-3dplot}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=test-\overlaynumber-]
\tikzsetexternalprefix{tikzpics/}
\usetikzlibrary{3D,
                    calc,%
                    decorations.markings,%
                    decorations.pathreplacing,%
                    external,%
                    positioning,%
                    circuits.logic.mux,%
                    shapes.gates.logic.US,%
                    shapes.geometric}
%\tikzset{node distance/.append code={ \pgfkeyssetvalue{/tikz/node distance value}{#1} }}   % it's supposed to allow retrieving node distance with \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/node distance value}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, table/search path={./dat},scaled ticks=false,%
            every axis/.append style={enlargelimits=false, axis on top,},%
            every mark/.append style={mark size=1pt, mark line=solid},%
            tick label style={font=\small, /pgf/number format/fixed}, label style={font=\small}, legend style={font=\small},%
            xlabel style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5,-5pt)},anchor=near ticklabel},%
            ylabel style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5,-5pt)},anchor=near ticklabel}}
\pgfdeclarelayer{back}
\pgfsetlayers{back,main}
\usepackage[americaninductors]{circuitikz}

\definecolor{mat1}{rgb}{0,0.447,0.7410}
\definecolor{mat2}{rgb}{0.8500,0.3250,0.0980}
\definecolor{mat3}{rgb}{0.9290,0.6940,0.1250}
\definecolor{mat4}{rgb}{0.4940,0.1840,0.5560}

% Rotated Data Flip Flip (DFF) shape
\pgfdeclareshape{dff}{
  % The 'minimum width' and 'minimum height' keys, not the content, determine
  % the size
  \savedanchor\northeast{%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgfshapeminwidth}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgfshapeminheight}%
    \pgf@x=0.5\pgf@x
    \pgf@y=0.5\pgf@y
  }
  % This is redundant, but makes some things easier:
  \savedanchor\southwest{%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{\pgfshapeminwidth}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\pgfshapeminheight}%
    \pgf@x=-0.5\pgf@x
    \pgf@y=-0.5\pgf@y
  }
  % Inherit from rectangle
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]

  % Define same anchor a normal rectangle has
  \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
  \anchor{north}{\northeast \pgf@x=0pt}
  \anchor{east}{\northeast \pgf@y=0pt}
  \anchor{south}{\southwest \pgf@x=0pt}
  \anchor{west}{\southwest \pgf@y=0pt}
  \anchor{north east}{\northeast}
  \anchor{north west}{\northeast \pgf@x=-\pgf@x}
  \anchor{south west}{\southwest}
  \anchor{south east}{\southwest \pgf@x=-\pgf@x}
  \anchor{text}{
    \pgfpointorigin
    \advance\pgf@x by -.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \advance\pgf@y by -.5\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox%
    \advance\pgf@y by +.5\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox%
  }

  % Define anchors for signal ports
  \anchor{D}{
    \pgf@process{\northeast}%
    \pgf@x=0pt%
    \pgf@y=-\pgf@y%
  }
  \anchor{CLK}{
    \pgf@process{\northeast}%
    \pgf@x=-1\pgf@x%
    \pgf@y=0pt%
  }
  \anchor{Q}{
    \pgf@process{\northeast}%
    \pgf@x=0pt%
    \pgf@y=\pgf@y%
  }
  % Draw the rectangle box and the port labels
  \backgroundpath{
    % Rectangle box
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\southwest}{\northeast}
    % Angle (>) for clock input
    \pgf@anchor@dff@CLK
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgf@xc=\pgf@x \pgf@yc=\pgf@y
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@x{.4ex} % size depends on font size
    \advance\pgf@ya by \pgf@x
    \advance\pgf@xb by \pgf@x
    \advance\pgf@yc by -\pgf@x
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}}
    \pgfclosepath

    % Draw port labels
    \begingroup
    \tikzset{flip flop/port labels} % Use font from this style
    \tikz@textfont

    \endgroup
  }
}

% Key to add font macros to the current font
\tikzset{add font/.code={\expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@textfont\expandafter{\tikz@textfont#1}}} 

% Define default style for this node
\tikzset{flip flop/port labels/.style={font=\sffamily\tiny}}
\tikzset{every dff node/.style={draw,minimum width=0.4cm,minimum 
height=0.4cm,inner sep=1mm,outer sep=0pt,cap=round,add 
font=\sffamily}}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=4mm and 4mm, circuit logic,every node/.style={font=\tiny},]%
    \ctikzset{bipoles/thickness=1}
    
    \node (data) at (0.5,0.3) [anchor=north]{data};
    \node [shape=dff, draw] (ff1) [above=of data] {FF};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The whole definition of shape `dff` and the option `add font` should be surrounded by a pair of `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. Check how https://texample.net/tikz/examples/d-flip-flops-and-shift-register/ did.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you very much. Now I wonder why I removed them in the first place... Anyway, any idea why that conflicted only with ``groupplots``? Is it because some macro names were multiply defined?

Comment: Maybe, I didn't checked this. I tested your example by commenting out both the `external` library staff and `groupplots` lib, then compiled and found error. Maybe it's the `external` lib that covered the problem before. After adding back `\makeat(letter|other)`, it worked fine with all things un-commented.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot.